Raylib c++ stops working after a certain amount of time
I made a snake program in c++ using raylib library. My game completely freezes after a certain amount of time (a few minutes).
Here is the full code of my program:
#include <iostream>
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"
#include <deque>

using namespace std;
  
// Constant Values
const int cell_size = 40; // Cell size has to be equal to assets dimension in pixels
const int cell_count_x = 20, cell_count_y = 15;
const int game_width = cell_size * cell_count_x;
const int game_height = cell_size * cell_count_y;
const int FPS = 60;
const int offset = cell_size * 2;
const int font_size = 40;

// Classes
class Food {
public:
    Vector2 position;
    Texture texture;

    Food(deque<Vector2> snake_body) {
        Image image = LoadImage("Graphics/apple.png");
        texture = LoadTextureFromImage(image);
        UnloadImage(image);
        position = GetRandomPos(snake_body);
    }

    ~Food() {
        UnloadTexture(texture);
    }

    void Draw() {
        DrawTexture(texture, offset + position.x * cell_size, offset + position.y * cell_size, WHITE);
    }

    Vector2 GetRandomPos(deque<Vector2> snake_body) {
        float x = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_x - 1);
        float y = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_y - 1);

        Vector2 position = { x, y };
        while (CheckPos(snake_body, position) == false) {
            float x = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_x - 1);
            float y = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_y - 1);
            Vector2 position = { x, y };
        }
        
        return position;
    }

    bool CheckPos(deque<Vector2> snake_body, Vector2 position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < snake_body.size(); i++)
            if (Vector2Equals(snake_body[i], position)) 
                return false;

        return true;
    }
};
 
class Snake {
public:
    deque<Vector2> body = { Vector2{cell_count_x / 3, cell_count_y / 3}, Vector2{cell_count_x / 3 - 1, cell_count_y / 3} , Vector2{cell_count_x / 3 - 1, cell_count_y / 3} };
    Vector2 direction = { 1, 0 };
    bool fruit_collision = false;

    void Draw() {
        for (int i = 0; i < body.size(); i++) {
            float x = body[i].x;
            float y = body[i].y;
            Rectangle body_part = Rectangle{ offset + x * cell_size, offset + y * cell_size, (float)cell_size, (float)cell_size };
            DrawRectangleRounded(body_part, 0.5, 10, DARKGREEN);
        }
    }

    void UpdateMovement() {
        if (fruit_collision)
            fruit_collision = false;
        else
            body.pop_back();

        body.push_front(Vector2Add(body[0], direction));
    }

    void UpdateDirection() {
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_UP) && direction.y != 1)
            direction = { 0, -1 };
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_DOWN) && direction.y != -1)
            direction = { 0, 1 };
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_LEFT) && direction.x != 1)
            direction = { -1, 0 };
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_RIGHT) && direction.x != -1)
            direction = { 1, 0 };
    }

    void Reset() {
        body = { Vector2{cell_count_x / 3, cell_count_y / 3}, Vector2{cell_count_x / 3 - 1, cell_count_y / 3} , Vector2{cell_count_x / 3 - 1, cell_count_y / 3} };
        direction = { 1, 0 };
    }
};

class Game {
public:
    Snake snake = Snake();
    Food food = Food(snake.body);

    double last_update_time = 0;
    int score = 0, max_score = 0;

    Sound food_sound, death_sound;

    Game() {
        InitAudioDevice();
        food_sound = LoadSound("Sounds/food_sound.mp3");
        death_sound = LoadSound("Sounds/death_sound.mp3");
    }

    ~Game() {
        UnloadSound(food_sound);
        UnloadSound(death_sound);
        CloseAudioDevice();
    }

    void Draw() {
        food.Draw();
        snake.Draw();
    }

    void DisplayText() {
        DrawText("Snake Game", offset, offset / 2, font_size, DARKGREEN);

        DrawText("Score: ", offset, offset + game_height + 5, font_size, DARKGREEN);
        DrawText(TextFormat("%i", score), offset + 150, offset + game_height + 5, font_size, DARKGREEN);

        DrawText("Max Score: ", offset + game_width - 260, offset + game_height + 5, font_size, DARKGREEN);
        DrawText(TextFormat("%i", max_score), offset + game_width - 15, offset + game_height + 5, font_size, DARKGREEN);
    }

    void Update() {
        snake.UpdateDirection();
        if (EventTriggered(0.2))
            snake.UpdateMovement();

        CheckCollisionWithFood();
        CheckCollisionWithEdge();
        CheckCollisionWithBody();
    }

    void CheckCollisionWithFood() {
        if (Vector2Equals(snake.body[0], food.position)) {
            food.position = food.GetRandomPos(snake.body);
            
            snake.fruit_collision = true;

            score++;

            PlaySound(food_sound);
        }
    }

    void CheckCollisionWithEdge() {
        if (snake.body[0].x >= cell_count_x || snake.body[0].x == -1 || snake.body[0].y >= cell_count_y || snake.body[0].y == -1)
            GameOver();
    }

    void CheckCollisionWithBody() {
        for (int i = 2; i < snake.body.size(); i++)
            if (Vector2Equals(snake.body[0], snake.body[i]))
                GameOver();
    }

    void GameOver() {
        snake.Reset();
        food.position = food.GetRandomPos(snake.body);

        if (score > max_score)
            max_score = score;
        score = 0;

        PlaySound(death_sound);
    }

    bool EventTriggered(double interval) {
        double current_time = GetTime();

        if (current_time - last_update_time >= interval) {
            last_update_time = current_time;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    InitWindow(game_width + offset * 2, game_height + offset * 2, "Snake");
    SetTargetFPS(FPS);

    // Game Class
    Game game = Game();

    // Main Loop
    while (WindowShouldClose() == false) {
        BeginDrawing();

        // Update
        game.Update();

        // Draw
        ClearBackground(GREEN);
        DrawRectangleLinesEx(Rectangle{ offset - 5, offset - 5, cell_size * cell_count_x + 10, cell_size * cell_count_y + 10 }, 5, DARKGREEN);
        game.Draw();
        game.DisplayText();

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}


If you haven't already done so, run the program under a debugger and wait for it to freeze up. Then pause the program and see where it is.  If you're lucky, it'll be locked up in a small loop you can easily step through with the debugger until you figure out why it never exits or on a blocking operation from which you can work back down the stacktrace to see how the program got there (and hopefully why its not getting unblocked). If you're unlucky you'll have to go more freeform in your investigation, but either way, gather information and use it to improve the question .

do you have the terminal open behind the application ? if yes then you need to press Enter on your keyboard with the terminal focused to get around the stupid windows terminal behavior of suspending your application if the terminal is focused, or compile your application without a terminal. (ie: subsystem = windows)

Checking for collisions only needs to be done after calling UpdateMovement, not every frame

Ernest, was the problem resolved by fixing the issue I mentioned in my answer? Is the answer acceptable as-is or is there something you'd like me to add/clarify?

The problem is in GetRandomPos where you declare a new position that shadows the position you intend to reassign:
Vector2 position = { x, y };
while (CheckPos(snake_body, position) == false) {  // position 1
    float x = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_x - 1);
    float y = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_y - 1);
    Vector2 position = { x, y };                   // position 2, shadows pos 1
}

The position you declare at the end inside the loop, directly goes out of scope and is destroyed. The position you use in your while condition stays unchanged.
This makes the game get stuck in an infinite loop whenever a random position which is on top of the snake body is selected. The position will never change.
Just reassign the position you already have instead:
Vector2 position = { x, y };
while (CheckPos(snake_body, position) == false) {
    float x = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_x - 1);
    float y = GetRandomValue(0, cell_count_y - 1);
    position = { x, y };                           // <- problem solved
}


Another note: You are passing std::deques around by value. These are pretty expensive to copy, so I advice you to take them by reference in the functions instead. Make it const& if the function shouldn't make changes to the deque and just & if it should.
